# Quantum nonlinear resonator/ transmon qubit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

The transmon qubit -quantum non-linear resonator- has 4 elements in the electrical circuit. ([Here is the circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKTNBN99xLw&t=1520s)) starting at the 21:00 mark.

We have R, L, C,Cd and Voltage.

I already know which L,C,Cd and Voltage I need to use and how powerful they should be in order to work at the level of quantum computing.

How much tolerance in ohm should the $R$ have in this case?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Do you know how to calculate the energy decay rate for a parallel LC resonator connected to a resistor?

Comment: No, i do not know the energy decay rate calculation. 

I found these 
C  = 100e-15;
Cr = 0.5*C;
L0 = 5e-9;

relative to these elements, in which range should i need to choose the Resistor?